# Hiding navbar in home state - ui-router / angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ng-if

I'm am trying to hide my navbar in my home state.
I currently have a working version but I don't like my solution, seeing I get a flicker everytime I load up the home page.

Currently I'm using:

```
<nav ng-if="$state.current.name !== 'home'" class="navbar navbar-default
     navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="navCtrl" class="ng-cloak">
```

As you can see, I've tried `ng-cloak` but this does not work for some reason. I did add it to css.

Is there an easier way to hide my navbar on my home state?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using ng-if? I was originally going to ask about show/hide, but that usually does load the element first resulting in a flicker. ng-if removes the DOM element.

Comment: @td-edge yes ofcourse, this gives the same result

Comment: Try putting ng-cloak as an attribute in your body tag

Comment: @imnotfred like I said, ng-cloak does not work for me for some reason. I have tried putting it in every tag, with no effect at all.

Comment: Instead of ng-if, maybe put the nav inside your home view

Comment: @imnotfred that makes no sence

Comment: @Borni I'm not sure how else to explain it. You have a home view, right? Put the nav in there and then you don't have to worry about the ng-if, because it will only show up in your home view

Comment: @imnotfred my home is also loaded in through a partial. I have my index.html, loading in all my scripts, css and navbar and within my container I have my ui-view loading in all the partials.

Comment: @imnotfred also, I want to not load the nav bar on home. It has to show on all other views